# InternetReadFile() reads data but returns false and sets number of bytes read to zero

Tags: winapi, wininet

Making an asynchronous request with Wininet, when the status callback function is called with INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE, I get the http status code.

```
result = HttpQueryInfo(
    this->requestHandle,
    HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
    &value,
    &sizeofDword,
    &index);
```

The status code returned is 200. After that, I call InternetReadFile().

```
result = InternetReadFile(
    this->requestHandle,
    ((char*)(this->buffer)) + this->totalBytesReceived,
    this->bufferSize - this->totalBytesReceived,
    &bytesRead);

this->totalBytesReceived += bytesRead;
```

It returns true and sets lpNumberOfBytesRead to zero. GetLastError() returns ERROR_IO_PENDING, then I wait the callback function is called again with INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE.

When that occurs, InternetReadFile() returns true and again sets lpNumberOfBytesRead to zero.

If I debug the application, I can see after the first InternetReadFile() that the response data is already on the lpBuffer. Moreover, if I call Sleep() for one second before InternetReadFile(), InternetReadFile() works correctly.

```
Sleep(1000);

result = InternetReadFile( ...
```

Am I missing any step?

Comment: So there's an InternetSetStatusCallback() somewhere in your code?  And the actual InternetReadFile() call that misbehaves is not the one you posted?  Hard to diagnose invisible code.

Comment: @HansPasant Yes, the InternetReadFile() that shows the wrong behavior is the one posted. Do you think I should post any other part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problem, and still the same even using Sleep(1000). I was connecting to a 3rd party camera stream, I've tried it on debug version, which worked perfectly. But when I went back to release version, it just wouldn't work.

I fixed it by changing HttpOpenRequest's lplpszAcceptTypes to NULL, then everything started working to work.

Seems like when WinINet dealing with internet connection, with different type of mobile phone / os /debug or release binary version/ have some kind of different operation which we can not possibly know.